# How many samples needed for a collision (birthday paradox)

Tags: python, math, discrete-mathematics, birthday-paradox

Just trying to understand birthday paradox.
Using a following code I figured out that I need on average **12 samples** to get a birthday collision.
Can not understand why it is much lower than *normal* 23 people to get a 1/2 chance of a birthday collision.
The result does not change even if I use StrongRandom from PyCrypto.

```
from random import randint
from Crypto.Random.random import StrongRandom
EXPERIMENTS_NUM = 10000
SET_SIZE = 365
SUBSET = 23

where_collision_found = list()
rnd = StrongRandom()
for experiment in range(EXPERIMENTS_NUM):
  for i in range(1,SET_SIZE + 2):
    collision_found = False
    #Generate a subset
    # subset = [rnd.randint(1, SET_SIZE) for x in range(i)]
    subset = [randint(1, SET_SIZE) for x in range(i)]
    # Check for collision
    flags = [False for x in range(SET_SIZE + 1)]
    for k in range(i):
      if flags[subset[k]]: #Collision found
        collision_found = True
      else:
        flags[subset[k]] = True

    if collision_found:
      # print 'Collision found in set:', subset
      break
  where_collision_found.append(i)
print 'average collision:', sum(where_collision_found) / float(len(where_collision_found)), 'in', EXPERIMENTS_NUM, 'experiments'
```

Result:
    `average collision: 12.1277 in 10000 experiments`

Comment: What is the significance of summing `where_collision_found`?

Comment: just to get the average: `sum / count`

Comment: `where_collision_found` is the day of the year or `366` if no collision. Taking its average isn't the probability of collision.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not looking for a probability. I'm looking for an average number of samples to get a collision. In this case it is 12, and I am wondering why this number as much lower than 23 or 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what your code is doing.  Here's what I did just now:

```
from random import randrange
N = 365
ns = []
for _ in range(10000):
    n = 0
    seen = set()
    while True:
        b = randrange(N)
        n += 1
        if b in seen:
            break
        seen.add(b)
    ns.append(n)
print(sum(ns) / float(len(ns)))
```

And output from a sample run:

```
24.6577
```

This is good.  The "23" you're expecting is the median of the distribution; the mean (average) is expected to be 24.61659 ...  See here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people

Comment: Thanks for clear illustration, but I still do not get why my code in not showing something about ~24...

Comment: I honestly don't know what your code is computing.  You're forcing subsets (really lists - selections with replacement) to be of many specific, increasing sizes, which has nothing to do with the underlying problem.  It's not the code that needs fixing - it's your modeling of the problem.  The code I gave shows a straightforward modeling of the problem - and, not too surprisingly, with a correct *model* the results are as expected too.

Comment: Well, in your example, each subset in the iteration is dependent on the previous one (because you just append a new value to it). I suppose it is not the best way of random sampling from some set. 
In my example I generate new subsets in each iteration and this somehow affects the outcome.
I think I really need to study the subject, but do not know where (wikipedia, unfortunately did not help)

Comment: You're not picking random subsets.  Suppose you only picked lists of length 2.  Then eventually you _will_ get a collision, and you'll "conclude" that the average # of people needed is 2.  Instead you actually pick lists of lengths 1, 2, 3, ... but the same basic bias is at work:  you're giving shorter lists more chances to collide than they "should have".  So you "conclude" the average needed is smaller than it really is.  The sampling method in my code isn't just simpler, it's also unbiased (proof left to the reader - but it's "obviously" just uniform random selection with replacement).

Comment: Sergey, if you're still baffled about this, consider what would happen if your loop on `i` went from largest to smallest instead.  Then every time, it would find a collision on the first try, and you'd "conclude" the average # of people needed is 366(!).  The ordering introduces bias.  The bias is just subtler going from smallest to largest instead.

Comment: Yes, now I understand, that smaller sets have a better chance to get a collision. Thank you!